# how to convert a unique number in to string using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I am unable to send a value to the service URL parameters using AJAX. The value is `6946602c34d442a6`. I am sending this value to the below URL:

```js
$('#btn').click(function() {
  var userName = $('#Username').val();
  var password = $('#password').val();
  var lg_dev = device.uuid;
  var lginfo = lg_dev.toString();
  var urlInfo = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xx/Service1.svc/log";

  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: urlInfo,
    data: "uid=" + userName + "&pwd=" + password + "&DeviceId=" + lginfo + "",
    success: function(resp) {
      var data1 = resp;
      console.log(data1);
    },
    error: function(e) {
      // SpinnerPlugin.activityStop();
      window.plugins.toast.showLongBottom("Invalid Data");
      // SpinnerPlugin.activityStop();
    }
  });
});
```

Till data part data is getting but later it directing towards to the error part directly and when debugged it. It is displaying this error:

[image]

and while using the postman i am able to get the day and below is the data which im using for login

```
    {
    "Id": "2",
    "DeviceID": "6956303c32d442a1",
    "Extension": "@nazu.nz",
    "Name": "nazu",
    "Password": "nazu",
    "UserName": "mxa",
    "sno": 3,
    "status": true
}
```

while debugging it is also going to jquery file

```
while ( ( handleObj = matched.handlers[ j++ ] ) &&
                !event.isImmediatePropagationStopped() ) {

                // Triggered event must either 1) have no namespace, or 2) have namespace(s)
                // a subset or equal to those in the bound event (both can have no namespace).
                if ( !event.rnamespace || event.rnamespace.test( handleObj.namespace ) ) {

                    event.handleObj = handleObj;
                    event.data = handleObj.data;

                    ret = ( ( jQuery.event.special[ handleObj.origType ] || {} ).handle ||
                        handleObj.handler ).apply( matched.elem, args );

                    if ( ret !== undefined ) {
                        if ( ( event.result = ret ) === false ) {
                            event.preventDefault();
                            event.stopPropagation();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

after this it is going to

```
// Call the postDispatch hook for the mapped type
    if ( special.postDispatch ) {
        special.postDispatch.call( this, event );
    }

    return event.result;
},
```

and then going to

```
callback = function( type ) {
                    return function() {
                        if ( callback ) {
                            callback = errorCallback = xhr.onload =
                                xhr.onerror = xhr.onabort = xhr.onreadystatechange = null;

                            if ( type === "abort" ) {
                                xhr.abort();
                            } else if ( type === "error" ) {

                                // Support: IE9
                                // On a manual native abort, IE9 throws
                                // errors on any property access that is not readyState
                                if ( typeof xhr.status !== "number" ) {
                                    complete( 0, "error" );
                                } else {
                                    complete(

                                        // File: protocol always yields status 0; see #8605, #14207
                                        xhr.status,
                                        xhr.statusText
                                    );
                                }
                            } else {
                                complete(
                                    xhrSuccessStatus[ xhr.status ] || xhr.status,
                                    xhr.statusText,

                                    // Support: IE9 only
                                    // IE9 has no XHR2 but throws on binary (trac-11426)
                                    // For XHR2 non-text, let the caller handle it (gh-2498)
                                    ( xhr.responseType || "text" ) !== "text"  ||
                                    typeof xhr.responseText !== "string" ?
                                        { binary: xhr.response } :
                                        { text: xhr.responseText },
                                    xhr.getAllResponseHeaders()
                                );
                            }
                        }
                    };
                };
```

[image]

Comment: Everything is sent as a string in a HTTP request, so type conversion is not your issue. Given the error message it appears you're simply missing a `resp` property somwhere.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan But when i checked the url with postman i able to get the data

Comment: are there any other code using the variable name `resp`?

Comment: That sounds like this is a possible CORS issue then. Check the console for errors after the request completes.

Comment: you might have used `resp` outside the `success` anonymous function.

Comment: The whole URL with query string is always passed as string. No matter whatever type your variables are of

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan CORS is not an isssue i checked it

Comment: Ok, well there must be an issue somewhere. Have you checked for any errors with the AJAX request?

Comment: @Rory McCrossan so u check the ajax  in my code right so there is no problem in that right?

Comment: No, the JS you've shown is fine. The issue is somewhere between the server processing the request and the returned data.

Comment: the error says `ReferenceError: resp is not defined`. Doesnt it mean that you referenced `resp` in a context where it doesnt exist/declared?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan while debugging it is going to jquery2.2.4 js which i am using   if ( ret !== undefined ) {
      if ( ( event.result = ret ) === false ) {
       event.preventDefault();
       event.stopPropagation();
      }
     }

Answer (score -1):

This should clarify things a little:

```
$('#btn').click(function() {
  var userName = $('#Username').val();
  var password = $('#password').val();
  var lg_dev = device.uuid;
  var lginfo = lg_dev.toString();
  var urlInfo = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xx/Service1.svc/log";

  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: urlInfo,
    data: {
      uid: userName,
      pwd: password,
      DeviceId: lginfo
    },
    success: function(data, status, xhr) {
      console.log(arguments);

      if (data) {
        var data1 = data;
      } else {
        console.log('Server sent an empty response.');
      }
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
       console.log('Ajax failed', arguments);
      // SpinnerPlugin.activityStop();
      window.plugins.toast.showLongBottom("Invalid Data");
      // SpinnerPlugin.activityStop();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: the OP's `$.ajax()` is fine.

Comment: @rrv you suppose it is fine, but the data passed in as a string should be encoded and in his case it isn't, Also he supposed the server responds with something and it might not be the case.

Comment: you are correct, but this doesnt answer the OP's question IMO.

Comment: @rrv he said he can't send a value to the server, with my version he should be able to send the value to the server. If he doesn't then he will come back with the eventual error or message he receives in console.Let's get analytical and constructive here :)

Comment: @bluehipy i  got ajax failed ,and server sent empty response as alerts

Comment: @TechieBoy so you have your next milestone, the problem is on your server responding with a null response. Debug what s happening on the server.

Comment: @But by using the postman  im able to get the data just check my update image of debugging

Comment: yeah but it's different, postman and your server side are not reacting the same way. Check on your server side the input and the output for this request.